# Tinymce drag and drop contenteditable = false on firefox produce duplicate element

Tags: javascript, firefox, duplicates, tinymce

[image]

In tinymce editor I have a non-editable element with contenteditable=false, If I drag this element under the end of editor in firefox, release the cursor and click somewhere in the edit area it will create a duplicate of that element. In Chrome everything works fine.

Is there anyway to prevent this behavior?